# Migrating from BrokeredMessage generic pump to ServiceBusReceivedMessage equivalent

Tags: .net, azureservicebus

Migrating from the legacy SB client method **client.OnMessageAsync()** in **Microsoft.ServiceBus** to **client.CreateProcessor()** in **Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus**, my current message processor parses the generic message via reflection, how can the same strategy be implemented in **Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus**?

```
public class AzureBusReceiver<T>
{
        public async Task OnReceived(BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage, T processor)
                {
                    var messageType = Type.GetType(brokeredMessage.Properties["messageType"].ToString());
                    var method = typeof(BrokeredMessage).GetMethod("GetBody", new Type[] { });
                    if (method != null)
                    {
                        var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(messageType);
                        var messageBody = generic.Invoke(brokeredMessage, null);
                        var args = new[] { messageBody };
                        try
                        {
                            await new DynamicProcessor<T>().Run(processor, messageType, args);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            // ignored
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done without using reflection, by simply deserializing the body and supplying the type as a param, and not as a return type in the method signature

```
 public class AzureBusReceiver<T>
    {
        public async Task OnReceived(ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, T processor)
        {
                
            var messageType = Type.GetType(message.ContentType);
            if (messageType != null)
            {
                var messageBody = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message.Body.ToString(), messageType);
                var args = new[] { messageBody };
                try
                {
                    await new DynamicProcessor<T>().Run(processor, messageType, args);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // ignored
                }
            }
        }
    }
```